# Cython project structure with dependent extension classes

Tags: import, cython, python-import, directory-structure

I'm getting to the point with a project where I need a proper directory structure. I'm trying to arrange this and getting `ImportError`s when using my cython extension classes.

The directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── foo.pxd
│   ├── foo.pyx
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── metafoo.pyx
└── test
    ├── test_foo.py
    └── test_metafoo.py
```

The contents of all files can be found (in commit e635617 at time of writing) of [this github repo](https://github.com/pearcemc/cython-example/).

My `setup.py` looks like the following:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, Command
from Cython.Build import cythonize

SRC_DIR = "src"
PACKAGES = [SRC_DIR]

ext_foo = Extension(SRC_DIR + ".foo",
                  [SRC_DIR + "/foo.pyx"]
                  )

ext_meta = Extension(SRC_DIR + ".metafoo",
                  [SRC_DIR + "/metafoo.pyx"]
                  )

EXTENSIONS = cythonize([ext_foo, ext_meta])

setup(
    name = 'minimalcriminal',
    packages=PACKAGES,
    ext_modules=EXTENSIONS
)
```

**The complexity seems to lie in that extension classes in `metafoo.pyx` use extension classes from  `foo.pyx`.**

After building with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, the `test_foo.py` program runs ok:

```
import os
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

import src.foo as foo

somefoo = foo.Foo(2)
somefoo.special_print()
```

When run from both the `cyproj/test` and `cyproj` directories:

```
/cyproj$ python test/test_foo.py
The value of somefield is: 2
```

and

```
/cyproj/test$ python test_foo.py 
The value of somefield is: 2
```

But the `test_metafoo.py` crashes when run in the `cyproj/test` directory:

```
import os
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

import src.foo as foo
import src.metafoo as metafoo

lotsafoo = [foo.Foo(i) for i in range(4)]

mf = metafoo.MetaFoo(lotsafoo)
mf.special_print()
```

With the message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-UX21E:/projects/cyproj/test$ python test_metafoo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_metafoo.py", line 6, in <module>
    import src.metafoo as metafoo
  File "cyproj/src/foo.pxd", line 6, in init cyproj.src.metafoo (src/metafoo.c:1154)
ImportError: No module named cyproj.src.foo
```

But runs properly from the parent `cyproj` directory:

```
/cyproj$ python test/test_metafoo.py
The value of somefield is: 0
The value of somefield is: 1
The value of somefield is: 2
The value of somefield is: 3
```

I don't really get what's driving the different behaviour of these errors. If I can't use `import src.foo` in `test_metafoo.py` why does it work in `test_foo.py`?

Similarly if I open up an interactive session in the parent directory and try to import all:

```
In [1]: from src import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7b8bc2c1dfb9> in <module>()
----> 1 from src import *

/projects/cyproj/cyproj/src/foo.pxd in init cyproj.src.metafoo (src/metafoo.c:1154)()

ImportError: No module named cyproj.src.foo
```

When `src/__init__.py` looks like:

```
__all__ = ["foo", "metafoo"]
```

Which I thought would allow importing all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile and test your package after removing the `__init__.py` file from the project root directory and changing `test_foo.py` and `test_metafoo.py`.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("."))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("../"))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. Out of interest why do we need to remove `__init__.py` from root? I guess I've misunderstood what I read about these files.

Comment: @conjectures at least your code looked like `cyproj` was not meant to be part of the package name, like `cyproj.src.foo` as in the `ImportError` message. When there is a `__init__.py` present in a directory, the name of the subdirectory will be a part of the package name.